# Issue when assigning Textbox value to Var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following Textbox:

```
<input type="textbox" name="number-of-standard-investors" class="enquiry" id="nostandinv" />
```

I'm attempting to assign the value of this Textbox to a var, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var number_of_standing_investments = $('#nostandinv').val(text);

    $("#nostandinv").keyup(function(){
        //console.log( number_of_standing_investments );

        alert( number_of_standing_investments );
    });
});
```

However number_of_standing_investments is never assigned the value, can anyone suggest what the issue is here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is a setter, and also the `text` isn't defined at this time, which throws a `ReferenceError`:

```
var number_of_standing_investments = $('#nostandinv').val(text);
```

You need to use a **getter**:

```
var number_of_standing_investments = $('#nostandinv').val();
```

Looks like you need to dynamically assign it while alerting it. So do this:

```
$("#nostandinv").keyup(function(){
    //console.log( number_of_standing_investments );
    number_of_standing_investments = this.value;
    alert( number_of_standing_investments );
});
```

And the scope of `number_of_standing_investments` is already in **global** scope, accessible to anything inside the `$(document)`'s `ready` function.

Comment: From: Performance perspective `number_of_standing_investments = this.value;` would be better

Comment: @Satpal Updated. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `number_of_standing_investments = $('#nostandinv').val();` inside keyup function.

One mistake I found was `$('#nostandinv').val(text)` it will show an error, because the variable text is not defined.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var number_of_standing_investments = $('#nostandinv').val();

    $("#nostandinv").keyup(function(){
         number_of_standing_investments = $('#nostandinv').val();
         alert( number_of_standing_investments );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="textbox" name="number-of-standard-investors" class="enquiry" id="nostandinv" />
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to make number_of_standing_investments accessible globally though?

Comment: @Liam as long as you are not declaring a variable with same name inside a different function its scope won't change. As per your code it is already global scope.

Comment: Interestingly in the JS fiddle I'm working in, this still does not work. https://jsfiddle.net/LiamFell/ctg6fk3a/9/

Comment: @Liam jsbin blocks `alerts`. `:)`

Comment: @Liam in your fiddle it is text(). that is not correct. Use val() to get value of  an input field

Comment: @PraveenKumar https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/ctg6fk3a/10/ fiddle is also working fine `:P`

Comment: @Liam Please dont forget to accept the answer if it helped you. It may help others also.

Answer (score 1):

Get value of textbox inside keyup. You are saving textbox value on ready state. So it will always store your initial value of textbox.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nostandinv").keyup(function(){
        //console.log( number_of_standing_investments );
        var number_of_standing_investments = $(this).val();
        alert( number_of_standing_investments );
     });
 });
```